# extract a part from an expression

Tags: php, sql

I have some expressions of the form aa/bbbb/c/dd/ee. I want to select only the part dd from it using a php code. Using 'substr' it can be done, but the problem is that the lengths of bbbb can vary from 3 (i.e., bbb) to 4, lengths of c can be 1 or 2 and the lengths of dd can be 2, 3 or 4. Then how can I extract the part dd (i.e, the part between the last pair  /  /).

Comment: You tagged this with sql. Is this how your data is stored in your database? Are you trying to do this in sql or your code?

Comment: You can use patindex to find the positions of the slash characters, and then those positions to formulate your Substring statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use explode to explode the string into an array and then grab the 4th item in the array which will be dd regardless of the size of the other elements, just make sure the number of '/' stays the same

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the expression always has the "/" separators even if the values in between are varying in length (or sometimes absent) you can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$parts_array = explode("/", $expression);
$dd = parts_array[3];
```

If the number of slashes varies, you'll have to do more work, like determining how many slashes there are and what parts of the expression are missing. That's a fair bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, the PHP script for selecting the text between the last pair of "/../":

```
<?php
    $expression = "aaa/vvv/bbbb/cccc/ddd/ee";
    $mystuff = explode("/", $expression);
    echo $mystuff[sizeof($mystuff)-2];
?>
```

I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: @suvadip If this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it. Good luck!